# How to solve recurrence. T(n). = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis, recursion, mathematical-analysis

I am aware that to get a running time by recursion tree method, we need to draw a tree and find:

**a) number of levels in tree**.

Since left side of tree decreases by 1 in size, so it's longest path from root. Subproblem size at level i is `n-i` . setting n - i = 1 when it hits a size of 1, we get number of levels, i  = n - 1.

**b) cost per node in tree** : `cn`

**c) Number of nodes at level i**:   This is where i am stuck. Not able to find nodes at level i since left side decreases by 1, right side by half. Naturally,  tree is more dense towards left side.  Not every node will have two children.

if i can get answer to c, i can calculate T(n) = cost of level 0 + cost of level 1 + cost of level 2 +  ... cost of level n-1. 
if y1 is number of nodes at level 1, y2 at level 2, etc... then
=> T(n) = cn + y1 * cn + y2 * cn + y3 * cn + .... yn-1 * cn  to get total cost.

Can anyone guide me to the approach i am taking ? is it correct ? 
can i take an assumption that for sufficiently large n,  we can ignore T(n/2) and then proceed  ? .

Online searching confused me. Problem is 4.4-5 from CLRS.

Please see [here](https://walkccc.github.io/CLRS/Chap04/4.4/#44-3)

This solution says T(n) = O(2^n) and T(n) = omega(n^2) and does not explain how.

Also see [here](https://atekihcan.github.io/CLRS/E04.04-05/)

This solution says T(n) = O(n^2).  but contradicts with above solution

Comment: It's a lovely problem. The T(n/2) is what makes it so nice, and it can absolutely not be ignored. Assume T(n) ≈ c n^k. Then T(n) ≈ c (n-1)^k + c (n/2)^k ≈ c (1 +2^-k)n^k - c n^(k-1) >> T(n). So the solution is not polynomial.

Comment: The problems you quote are all different. It's very difficult to get an idea by looking at the formula only. (Well, Yuval can... ) Using a spreadsheet it looks like T(n) = n ^ f(n), where f(n) is a quite slowly growing function. If T(1) = 1 then T(n) ≈ n^3 for n around 130 or so, T(n) = n^2.5 for n around 38.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $S(n) = T(n) - 2n - 2$. You can check that $S(n) = S(n-1) + S(n/2)$ (ignoring the fact that $n/2$ need not be an integer). This shows that the additive $n$ term doesn't make a big difference.

For large $n$, we have roughly $S(n) - S(n-1) \approx S'(n)$, and so we are led to solve the differential equation
$$
S'(n) = S(n/2).
$$
Consider $f(n) = \exp (\tfrac{1}{2}\log_2^2 n)$. Then
$$
f'(n) = \exp (\tfrac{1}{2}\log_2^2 n) \cdot \frac{\ln n}{(\ln 4)n},
$$
whereas
$$
f(n/2) = \exp(\tfrac{1}{2} (\log_2 n - 1)^2) \approx \exp(\tfrac{1}{2}\log^2 n) \exp(-\log n) = \exp(\tfrac{1}{2} \log^2 n) \cdot \frac{1}{n}.
$$
This suggests that, at the very least, $\ln S(n) = \Theta(\log^2 n)$.

Where does this come from? You can think of $S(n)$ (with an appropriate base case!) as the number of ways to go from $n$ to zero by applying two operations: subtract 1 and divide by 2. A "typical" such sequence will contain roughly $\log_2n$ many operations of the second type, out of $\Theta(n)$ operations in total, leading to the very rough estimate $\binom{\Theta(n)}{\log_2 n}$, which is also of the form $\exp \Theta(\log^2 n)$.

---

Consider for concreteness the following precise definition of $S(n)$: the base case is $S(0) = 1$, and for $n > 0$,
$$
S(n) = S(n-1) + S(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor).
$$
This is sequence [A000123](http://oeis.org/A000123). Knuth, [An almost linear recurrence](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/4-2/knuth.pdf), showed that
$$
\log_4 S(n) \sim \log_4^2 n,
$$
that is, the ratio of the two terms tends to 1 as $n \to \infty$. The OEIS entry contains even more precise asymptotics.

Comment: I find exp (log^2 n) hard to imagine, but its the same as (exp (log n)) ^ log n = n^(log n). So it's a power of n, with a slowly growing exponent.

Comment: @Yuval  Thanks for the response. how do you conclude S(n) - S(n-1) = S'(n) ?.  Sorry if it's lame, I am a beginner in CS theory.  Also how did you come up with f(n) = exp(1/2 log^n ) ?  .  why this particular function ?

Comment: The mean value theorem states that for a nice enough function, $S(n) - S(n-1) = S'(n+\theta)$ for some $\theta \in [0,1]$. If $n$ is large then $S'(n+\theta) \approx S'(n)$, for some meaning of $\approx$.

Comment: I came up with $f(n)$ by trial-and-error. With more trial-and-error, it should be possible to come up with an even better solution.

Answer (score -2):

I disagree with the Fibonacci hypnosis, but I'm not hundred percent sure of my answer

You see
$ T(n)= T(n-1) +c*n = O(n ^2) $

$ T(n) = T(n/2) + c*n =O(n log n) $

However, u don't get ur T(n) by straightforward adding.

If u go one level in the recursion (u can draw a tree)

T(n) =T(n-2) +T((n-1)/2) +T(n/2-1)+ T(n/4) 
+ [n + (n-1) + (n-1)/2 + (n/2-1) +n/4]

This to show u it is also not just
      $ O(n^2) $

I have to complete it, but I suspect either $ O((n^2) * log n) $
 or
   $ O((n^2) * n ^ {log n} ) = O(n^3) $

{There is a term n(1+1/2+1/4+..1/n) that decays in log n steps, I have to check again}

Comment: You are  right, I'm very sorry. I'll edit my answer, or maybe delete it temporarily.